# Remove space between 2 rows

Tags: html

This is my html

```
<table >

                 <tr>
                     <td></td>

                     <td   style="width: 180px;text-align: right">2323</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td  style="width: 180px" >GGGG</td>

                </tr>

                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong > Test</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td  style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">&nbsp;   </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
```

Here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/42jQF/)

You can see there is gap between text "Test" and the line

How to remove this space?

I tried using `style="border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse"`

Comment: Well its not a gap, its another table cell... just remove it and move that border to cell containing "Test" text

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/42jQF/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**replace**

```
<tr>
   <td><strong > Test</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">&nbsp;   </td>
</tr>
```

**with**

```
<tr>
   <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><strong > Test</strong></td>
</tr>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/42jQF/4/)

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with my table structure as per @JukkaKKorpela

Comment: @Happy Yes...as i mentioned in answer the trs which you need to replace had second Tr having `nbsp;` and `border-bottom` inline style that was taking the space...so i have asked you to delete it and add inline style to td which contains `text`

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove any text from td with border
2. Set border in td contains "Test"

fixed? js fiddle.net/42jQF/2/

Answer (score 1):

Put the style on that line?

```
 <table cellspacing="0">

                 <tr>
                     <td></td>

                     <td style="width: 180px;text-align: right">2323</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td  style="width: 180px" >GGGG</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000"><strong> Test</strong></td>

                </tr>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use

```
<td  style="border-top: 1px solid #000">&nbsp;</td>
```

or

```
<td  style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">Test</td>
```

The "gap" you are referring to is actually a cell beneath your Test value with bottom border.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I upvoted but will accept Dipesh Parmar answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The gap is caused by the last row of the table containing the no-break space `&nbsp;`, which makes the content as high as a line of text. So removing the `&nbsp;` would seem to solve the immediate problem.

However, it is illogical to set a border on a dummy cell when you can set it on a real cell. Moreover, the table structure is abnormal, since the rows have different numbers of cells. (An HTML5 validator would issue a warning about this, for good reasons.) Fixing this would however require information about the intended structure of the real table (the one in the question is presumably a strongly simplified version).

Comment: How should be structure of table then? Cant understood whats wrond with my table structure

Comment: http://validator.w3.org says (three times): “A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).” The fix depends on what the table is supposed to represent.